# Load multiple bindings with Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I am trying to load bindings in a class for a project. I am using 3rd party extensions for Caching and the class I need to load looks like below using c# and .net framework 472 .

```
public class CouchbaseCache : ICouchbaseCache, IDistributedCache
{
    public CouchbaseCache(ICouchbaseCacheBucketProvider provider, IOptions<CouchbaseCacheOptions> options);

    public IBucket Bucket { get; }
    public CouchbaseCacheOptions Options { get; }
}
```

usually, If I have to load, I would use something like 
    Bind().To().InSingletonScope();

But how would I do it for the above class by giving the bucket info and Options as values while loading it? I could not get my head around it.

Also, ICouchbaseCachebucketProvider is an interface derived from INamedbucketProvider and  derived class looks like

```
public interface INamedBucketProvider
{
    string BucketName { get; }

    IBucket GetBucket();
}
```

So far, I was able to get CouchbaseClientDefinition set up like this

```
Bind<ICouchbaseClientDefinition>().ToMethod(ctx =>
{
      var options = new CouchbaseClientDefinition
      {
           Servers = new List<Uri>
           {
                new Uri("http://couchbase.com/")
            }
       };
       return options;
 }).InSingletonScope();
```

I need to give Uri for couchbase and also bucket name and the logic is all over the place. Any knowledge sharing will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if the argument for the constructor of the CouchbaseCache is identical for the whole application life time then you can bind it with the use of *binding with constructor arguments* something like this where you are loading:

```
    var options = new CouchbaseClientDefinition
      {
           Servers = new List<Uri>
           {
                new Uri("http://couchbase.com/")
            }
       };
    var couchbaseCacheBucketProvider= new CouchbaseCacheBucketProvider
    {
        ...
    };



 Bind<ICouchbaseClientDefinition().To<CouchbaseCache >()
            .WithConstructorArgument(couchbaseCacheBucketProvider, options);
```

but you have to provide the couchbaseCacheBucketProvider.

if the arguments are different but they are limited for example if you have two version of the arguments you can use the named binding like this

```
           var options1 = new CouchbaseClientDefinition
            {
                ...
            };

            var options2 = new CouchbaseClientDefinition
            {
                ...
            };

            var couchbaseCacheBucketProvider1= new CouchbaseCacheBucketProvider
            {
                ...
            };
            var couchbaseCacheBucketProvider2= new CouchbaseCacheBucketProvider
            {
                ...
            };



            Bind < ICouchbaseClientDefinition().To<CouchbaseCache>().WithConstructorArgument(couchbaseCacheBucketProvider, options1).Named("FirstBinding");
            Bind < ICouchbaseClientDefinition().To<CouchbaseCache>().WithConstructorArgument(couchbaseCacheBucketProvider, options2).Named("SecondBinding");
```

However another Alternative is to use the FactoryPattern/Singleton to create your CouchbaseCache object. Then you need just to inject the Factory Class that you created and you can use the Factory Class to get the required CouchbaseCache object whenever it is required.